# UIWebView freezes when text is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, freeze, uimenucontroller

My app, on very rare occasions, freezes when I select text in a UIWebView. Here's how it happens:

1. Tap and hold to select text
2. Text gets selected
3. Whole app freezes, unresponsive to touch, but I can still see operatings running
4. May freeze for around 10s. After that the UIMenuController appears. If I try to scroll while it is freezing, the scrolling happens after the app is responsive again
5. If the text is still selected, it freezes again if I scroll. Happens again and again
6. If I managed to scroll the selected text out of the view, scrolling the rest of the webview is fine, until I scroll the selected text back
7. If I get out of the UIViewController containing the UIWebView, I can confirm that they are both deallocated. Go back into a new UIViewController with UIWebView and it happens again.
8. This continues to happen with new instances of UIWebView, and even when I close and resume the app. Only stops if I force a restart of the app.

Does anyone have any clue how I can debug this? I've never seen this in simulator. Only happens very rarely on device.

Comment: Can you get it to happen while profiling the app using `Instruments`?  Might help you to see what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried quitting all other apps while running your app?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you either have set up your view hierarchy improperly, or have modified it on a thread not the main thread. So tell us exactly where the UIWebView resides (super views), and take a good look at code that modifies sub view arrays.

For instance, you don't add the web view to a UINavigationController's sub views directly, but to its view controllers array etc.

All else fails create a demo project that also displays the problem and upload it to DropBox where we can run it ourselves.